# Why doesn't BibTeX work?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, kile

For some reason, I am not able to do any citations or even my bibliography. I get a "[BibTeX] finished with exit code 2" message when I compile in Kile. Yet, all seems to be ok in my bibliography.

Here is what I'm doing in my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[sort,round]{natbib} %package for bibliography
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}%unsrtnat sets as sorted by order of appearance

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}

Citation: \nocite{*}

Citation with something: \citep{CHANCE1952}

\section{Bibliography}
\bibliography{/home/my/path/to/library/test}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs

[image: this]

Here is what my library has (yes, only one reference for testing purposes)

```
@article{CHANCE1952,
   author = {Chance, B. and Greenstein, D. S. and Roughton, F. J.},
   title = {The mechanism of catalase action. I. Steady-state analysis},
   journal = {Arch Biochem Biophys},
   volume = {37},
   number = {2},
   pages = {301-21},
   note = {CHANCE, B
GREENSTEIN, D S
ROUGHTON, F J W
Not Available
Arch Biochem Biophys. 1952 Jun;37(2):301-21.},
   keywords = {*Oxidoreductases
Testis/*anatomy & histology},
   year = {1952}
}
```

and I'm compiling by doing `PDFLatex > Bibtex >pdflatex > pdflatex >viewpdf`. Could someone please help me out?

Thank you in advance!

***Edit: here is part of Bibtex's output to the file `.blg`***

```
...
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I couldn't open style file authordate1.bst
---line 2 of file test.aux
 : \bibstyle{authordate1
 :                      }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file test.aux
You've used 1 entry,
...
```

Comment: Your files work without error (I just changed the path to test.bib)

Comment: Then I really have no idea what is wrong.. Maybe natbib is not correctly installed? Also, I tried having the bibliography file in the same location as the latex file, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try it first with just `\bibliography{test}` with test.bib being in the current directory. Also try it directly on the command line rather than through an IDE.

Comment: bibtex will leave a `.blg` log file. What does it say?

Comment: I'll post in the main message

Comment: well that's fairly clear then:-) You don't have the natbib bibtex styles installed

Comment: In TL2013 I get `$ kpsewhich authordate1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/authordate1.bst`

Comment: ugh... off to google then. Would you like to add these as an answer so that I can accept it? If there is any link that I could follow I would appreciate as well ;) Also, what is TL2013? Thanks so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bibtex log shows you are missing the bibtex style your document specifies.

In TL2013 If I run the command

```
 kpsewhich authordate1.bst
```

Then it shows that style is located at

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/authordate1.bst
```

You could get the file from ctan but it should be more easily installable via whatever package system your tex distribution is using.

Comment: Indeed, after installing the style it worked perfectly! :) (in case someone is wondering, I installed by searching `texlive-bibtex-extra` in `Synaptic`). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the path of your bibliography (`\bibliography{/home/my/path/to/library/test}`), when i'm not wrong then the path is relative to your main latex file.

When i throw all the content in one file, it [seems to work](https://www.writelatex.com/246354vjzjzv):

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{CHANCE1952,
   author = {Chance, B. and Greenstein, D. S. and Roughton, F. J.},
   title = {The mechanism of catalase action. I. Steady-state analysis},
   journal = {Arch Biochem Biophys},
   volume = {37},
   number = {2},
   pages = {301-21},
   note = {CHANCE, B
GREENSTEIN, D S
ROUGHTON, F J W
Not Available
Arch Biochem Biophys. 1952 Jun;37(2):301-21.},
   keywords = {*Oxidoreductases
Testis/*anatomy & histology},
   year = {1952}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[sort,round]{natbib} %package for bibliography
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}%unsrtnat sets as sorted by order of appearance

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}

Citation: \nocite{*}

Citation with something: \citep{CHANCE1952}

\section{Bibliography}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also get the correct output out of your link, but not out of kile.
@JLDiaz no, I'm not including `.bib`

Answer (score 1):

I think kile is printing the version number of biber as exit code. Also logs in blg file does not show any errors.